# Tokens missing in Webform Emails after upgrading

Tags: views, webforms, i18n-l10n, tokens

Currently running Drupal 7.69 / PHP 7.3 (+ CiviCRM)

I have recently updated some Modules : Webform, Views Bulk Operations, i18n, and Content Access.
Since then, my Webform Emails do not show the pertaining tokens (but they just show the token titles) :

All those tokens are not populated :
[submission:completed_date:long],
[submission:user],
[submission:values],
[submission:url]

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem, but an issue still remains.

I have disabled Token and Entity Tokens Modules (and requested associated Modules)

... then reactivated :

The probem comes from the Advanced User Management Module : when it is enabled, most of the tokens cannot be browsed (among which the default proposed ones in the mail content).

... So, I cannot use this Module any more.